# java equivalent asterisk (*) in clojure?

Tags: java, clojure

To compile whole set of classes we write **" Library/* "** (in Java). what is clojure equivalent to this?
**Compiling using REPL.**

Comment: "Compiling" with just the compiler/REPL? Or using leiningen or maven? Could specify some more detail please?

Comment: @Sander I have updated the Question. thnx!

Comment: I'm not really sure what this question is asking. Do you mean what is the equivalent to writing "javac Library/*.java"? Or how to import classes (as Sander explains well below)?

Answer (score 3):

In general you have 3 ways of loading files/libraries into the REPL:

- Use
- Require
- Import

Use is the most powerfull (and also most dangerous).

Require tells the REPL that you are going to use items from that namespace. For example:

```
(require 'clojure.string)
```

allows you to do:

```
(clojure.string/split "hi, reader" #",")
```

Use does the same as Require, however use also includes all the vars of the ns into your current namespace.

Import is used with java libraries, like so:

```
(import 'java.util.Date)
```

so you can

```
(Date.)
```

Require (and therefore Use) uses a number of other functions "under the hood":

```
(require '[clojure.test :as test] :verbose)
 (clojure.core/load "/clojure/template")
 (clojure.core/load "/clojure/walk")
 (clojure.core/in-ns 'clojure.template)
 (clojure.core/alias 'walk 'clojure.walk)
 (clojure.core/in-ns 'clojure.test)
 (clojure.core/alias 'temp 'clojure.template)
 (clojure.core/load "/clojure/test")
```

So you can also simulate require by doing these steps manually.

Another interesting function is load-file

```
(load-file "src/mylib/core.clj")
```

and load

```
(load "address_book/core")
```

these load Clojure code from resources in classpath. A path is interpreted as
classpath-relative if it begins with a slash or relative to the root
directory for the current namespace otherwise.

If you want to load anything more complex then say 2 or 3 files, I seriously recommend using Leiningen.

edit: you might also want to use:

```
(add-classpath "file:///home/../.../src/")
```

To easily add files to the classpath, so you can use them with require.